# Random data in defaultProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React for quite a long time and I've encountered an interesting problem: basically, I want to use `defaultProps` as *`fallbackProps`* - that's what they are for, but there's one difficulty - both `defaultProps` property from stateless / `class extend Component` API and cached `getDefaultProps()` from `React.createClass` API are immutable (and constant).

Example:

```
var ExampleComponent = React.createClass({
    getDefaultProps: function () {
        return {
            number: Math.random()
        };
    }
    // ...
});

// or equivalent with ES6 classes

class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
    // ...
}

ExampleComponent.defaultProps = {
    number: Math.random()
};

// then...

<main>
    <ExampleComponent />            // cached random
    <ExampleComponent />            // cached random
    <ExampleComponent number={1} /> // 1
    <ExampleComponent />            // cached random
    <ExampleComponent />            // cached random
</main>
```

The problem is, that I want *dynamic* `defaultProps` - separate for each component instance.

Example:

```
<main>
    <ExampleComponent />            // fresh random
    <ExampleComponent />            // fresh random
    <ExampleComponent number={1} /> // 1
    <ExampleComponent />            // fresh random
    <ExampleComponent />            // fresh random
</main>
```

I know, it's easy to achieve that behavior with `state` (`getInitialState` is *per-component*), but I'm wondering if it is possible with no state and no HOC or similar approach.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. This is possible by using ES5 getters to define the `defaultProps` object:

```
ExampleComponent.defaultProps = Object.create({}, {
  number: {
    enumerable: true,
    get: () => Math.random()
  }
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsbin.com/rokuyomuza/1/edit?js,output)</kbd>

As you noticed, `defaultProps` is a static member, and as such is only initialized once per class. However, when `React.createElement` is called, it creates a new copy of `defaultProps` by enumerating through all of the properties and copying them to a new, blank object (this enumeration is why `enumerable: true` had to be set in the descriptor). [Relevant part of React's source](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3c3c30a19a25fd542861e97f197d22b8f4c586de/src/isomorphic/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L198-206):

```
  // Resolve default props
  if (type && type.defaultProps) {
    var defaultProps = type.defaultProps;
    for (propName in defaultProps) {
      if (props[propName] === undefined) {
        props[propName] = defaultProps[propName];
      }
    }
  }
```

`defaultProps[propName]` invokes the getter, which causes a new random number to be generated, which is then stored in `props`.

Comment: Okay, that's quite neat, but it will generate random number **every time I'll access it** - it's too heavy (in general and especially in my use case) - it's _**almost**_ equivalent of `const number = this.props.number || Math.random()`.

Comment: How often do you want it to update? It might be possible to write a more complicated getter to cache results and lighten it. What is your use case?

Comment: _Once per created_ component - as in my example - that's the way, how `defaultProps` works.

Comment: Okay, great! That worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks for that link to the React source.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a random "unique" id for my modals, thats why i did the following:

```js
const Modal = () => { // my component
    const id = useMemo(() => {
        // this will be run only once on "mount"
        return `modal-${randomNumber(1111,9999)}`;
    }, []); // empty array is important!

    return <div id={id}>Model {id}</div>;
};

/**
 * Random number between min (including) and max (excluding)
 * @param {number} min
 * @param {number} max
 * @return {number}
 */
const randomNumber = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor(
        (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min
    );
};
```

It's kind of a solution to your problem, except it's not using `defaultProps`. On the other hand, it won't give you a random id every time it re-renders, like @quw solution.
Maybe it's useful for some folks out there.

<kbd>[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-shtern-4cnxn)</kbd>